# Weird time formatted data between 1 and 2400

Tags: database, time, powerbi, format, powerquery

I'm using some open data for a project and the time fields are formatted as integers between 1 and 2400. How do I convert this into normal time?

(I'm using Power Bi for this project)

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/usdot/flight-delays?resource=download&select=flights.csv

Comment: I suggest you analyse the data and see whether common and obvious features like 60 minutes in an hour and 24 hours in a day could be mapped to the column somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

The columns seem to be in hour and minute format - HHMM . 0007 being 12.07am and 2315 being 11.15pm

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjAwMFeK1YlWMjI2NFWKjQUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Time.FromText([Column1],[Format = "HHmm", Culture = "en-GB"]), type time)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: I just figured this out shortly before you posted it. Thank you though!
I wonder why they store data like this

Comment: Integers compress well, could be a factor.